# req.user.roles = undefined?

Tags: javascript

**code:**

```
function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log(req.user.roles);
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
}
```

**output:**

```
{
  _id: 5bdf8d3bad3c971860134f6e,
  username: 'mark-rodgers',
  password: 'HASHCENSORED',
  display_name: 'Mark Rodgers',    
  email: 'test@test.com',
  created: 2018-11-05T00:22:19.126Z,
  roles: [ 'admin' ],
  __v: 0
}

undefined
```

I'm baffled. Can someone explain? When I `console.log(req.user)` I can clearly see there is a property called *roles* which contains an array. But I for the life of me can't access get that array to check if the user is an admin? *req.user.username*, *.password*, *.display_name*, etc all returns properly but logging *req.user.roles* returns undefined.

My goal is to check if "admin" exists in the array: req.user.roles

Answer (score 3):

Weird... Not sure why this matters but I hadn't added the "roles" field to my User model. So I guess even if the data is visibly there in req.user you can't access fields that aren't predefined in your model.. very interesting. If anyone has an additional explanation about why this is that would be great!

[image]

Comment: `req.user` is an instance of your user model, and by your previous definition didn't have a roles property, but DB did so it returned it, so the data was there just you couldn't access it. Calling console.log on mongoose model itself will just return the data that the DB returned which is why `roles` shows up in the console.

Comment: @dotconnor is there a method for printing out the model instead using console.log for debugging that I can use to prevent this in the future if I forget?

Comment: You can try taking a look at the `.toObject()` or `toJSON()` methods but other than that I'm not sure